# File_get_contents failed to open stream: http request failed 404 not found

Tags: php, svg

I need to add an svg file to a website and apply a class to this svg. This is frustrating, I've tried different solutions posted on here and none of them have worked for me. This worked on a different server, but after being moved to a new server it no longer works. Here is how I am calling it in the php:

```
<?php $svg = file_get_contents("http://www.folklorecoffee.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/folkloretextwhite-1.svg");
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($svg);
    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('svg') as $element) {
        $element->setAttribute('class','logo-light');  
    }
    $dom->saveHTML();
    $svg = $dom->saveHTML();    
    echo $svg;?>
```

I'm getting these warnings:

WARNING:  file_get_contents(http://www.folklorecoffee.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/folkloretextwhite-1.svg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in /home/folklorecoffee/public_html/wp-content/themes/lily/header.php on line 34

WARNING:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input in  /home/folklorecoffee/public_html/wp-content/themes/lily/header.php  on line 36

But when I test the url in my browser, it comes up fine. Not sure why I'm getting a 404 error. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it on the same host? If so, try with curl from a shell or even better, why not use the local path instead? Just assuming because I went on the site and the error's on your front-page.

Comment: More than likely the people of folklorecoffee.com don't want you scraping their content, so they make their website return 404 errors for requests without a user agent. Why not just save it to your server?

Comment: It's the same host, sorry for not clarifying that. It doesn't work with a local path either, same error. Warning: File_get_contents(folkloretextwhite-1.svg): failed to open stream: no such file or directory in /home/folklorecoffee/public_html/wp-content-themes/lily-header.php on line 34

Answer (score 0):

The request is working for me:

```
echo $svg = file_get_contents("http://www.folklorecoffee.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/folkloretextwhite-1.svg"); // prints the SVG data as expected
```

You could try the same request via a different mechanism, such as cURL:

```
$url = "http://www.folklorecoffee.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2018/04/folkloretextwhite-1.svg";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data; // prints the SVG data as expected
```

But if the URL is the same, I expect you will get the same result.

Given the above, the best answer is for you to do troubleshooting on your own about what is happening, since it is very specific to your setup.

You may gain some insight by looking at the Apache logs for the request. Does it show up? Does the URL it displays match what you expect?

Can you make other requests with `file_get_contents` to your domain that work? To the uploads folder? To other domains?

Check with your hosting provider to see if they can explain. There may be a configuration item that is interfering in some way.

Finally, you may want try investigating more carefully why the logo cannot be loaded from the file system. Is it a permissions issue? Can you load any file from the permissions directory?

Answer (score 0):

I tried everyone's suggestions and I thank you all for taking your time to try to offer help, I was never able to get it to work and continued to get the same error.

Interestingly any file on my server that I tried to call with file_get_contents would get the 404 error. It didn't matter if I did a local path or the exact url, the paths were correct. Here's what it's interesting: it would work if I pointed to a file that was NOT on my server. So I'm thinking there must be a configuration setting somewhere that I would need to change. I do not know what this setting would be and if someone out there is reading this and experiencing the same issues I hope this helps point you in the right direction.

I was in a time crunch and decided instead to simply write the svg file in with an object tag and that did the trick for now. I'd prefer using a different method, and I'll revisit this again in the future and update this post if I figure out what would fix it. Thank you again for all of your help, I hope this helps someone else.